# What is the step-by-step process of upgrading Openstack deployed by Kolla-Ansible?

Tags: openstack, upgrade, kolla-ansible

I'm afraid of following [this page](https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/latest/user/operating-kolla.html)'s instructions for updating the OpenStack as it does not seem to consider all aspects and is not written to upgrade service-by-service. No rollback solution is also provided.

I searched for detailed documentation for upgrading but was not found.

If you have already had the experience to upgrade OpenStack by Kolla, What are the steps to go to the next version, per service, per node?